# How to use the NuGet packages.config file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I see a ***packages.config*** file for each of my projects in a solution. It contains info about various assemblies info. I am expecting that the NuGet will automatically scan these packages.config and download as necessary. But it didn't. Do I need to manually install all the packages?

Comment: Have you got Tools->options->Package Manager->Allow NuGet to download missing packages checked?

Comment: Make sure packages.config is included in the visual studio project, otherwise it will not be used.

Comment: @L-Three Yes, the packages.config is included in the project.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you right click the project in question you can select "Manage nuGet Packages" from the menu. After you do that you can click "installed packages" on the left hand side to see the packages that you currently have installed. These are what you are seeing in your "packages.config" file. If you wish to update the packages or reinstall them you can do that through the interface here by clicking "uninstall", then finding them in the list an re-installing them again.

Alternatively you can use the package manager console to do things like updating, installing older versions or all sorts of things with the nuget manager. [See here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console) for some details about that. (Information about updating a package is at the bottom of the page).

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks. And I find that NuGet promopt me with a Restore command for downloading the missing packages.

Comment: When I add something as a reference to a project, I don't always see it getting updated in the packages.config. I am trying to understand:
When does packages.config get updated and when does it not?

Comment: @SrayanGuhathakurta Check your project file for a [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files), which has [superseded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) `packages.config` going forward.