# I need to provide "proof" of framework and Nuget package upgrade

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

So here goes, I'm in the process of upgrading the framework of multiple Projects within a large web applications.  The process is pretty straightforward I"m going from 4.5 to 4.7 and I'm upgrading a few of the Nuget packages.  I'm going to provide a word document with screenshots, however is there something "automatic" within Visual Studio that can generate a report of the current framework and list of nuget packages.

My problem is I have one project that has 20 or so Nuget packages and I have to do several screenshots to get them all.  I don't want to do this again to show before/after.

Comment: Look into your [packages.config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24556580/11683)?

Comment: Thanks,  How about is there a way to show the .NET framework of the SPECIFIC application on a web server.  I understand how to find the .NET framework installed by going thru the registry.

Comment: you may use corflags to determine which version of .net your website was compiled over: https://serverfault.com/a/322767 . Check additional links to supported and required runtime elements in that post.

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue? Please check if my answer helps, if the issue persists, feel free to let me know:)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [DTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.dte?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) to get any details about projects inside of VisualStudio.

#### TargetVersion

Open `Package Manager Console` (Tools -> Nuget Package Manager) and execute below command to select target version of the projects inside of your solution:

```
$dte.Solution | Select-Object -Property ProjectName, {$_.Properties["TargetFrameworkMoniker"].Value }
```

#### Nuget package version

Nuget package could be added to `packages.json` or to `.csproj` file as [package reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files). In both cases you can use DTE to get list of [packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/vslangproj150.packagereferences?view=visualstudiosdk-2017):

```
# below is an example for the first project
$project = $dte.Solution | select -first 1 
$project.Object.PackageReferences
```

I wasn't able to get nuget version from that object though. So I assume you just get keys and then use [$project.Object.References](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/vslangproj.references?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) to get required details (version/path...). If you know list of packages, then you can skip step 1.

#### Good old XML

Another option is to parse `.csproj` and `package.config` files and extract required details from there, [here is powershell example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788831/list-of-nodes-in-a-particular-node-in-csproj-file-with-powershell).

Answer (score 0):

> however is there something "automatic" within Visual Studio that can
>   generate a report of the current framework and list of nuget packages.

I'm afraid not, as I know VS doesn't have this feature to generate a report. You can easily see the project's framework by right-clicking the `project=>project properties` in solution explorer.

And as for the list of nuget packages, you can find the content you want in `packages.config` file.

> I have one project that has 20 or so Nuget packages and I have to do
>   several screenshots to get them all. I don't want to do this again to
>   show before/after.

The `packages.config` file have listed all nuget packages the project references though it's not a report.

And it seems you're upgrading your project to higher target framework, you can use the `Nuget Package Manager UI` to update them or `Package Manager Console` to update them.

**Update packages by UI:**

[image]

**Update package by command in VS:**

We can use [Package Manager Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell#find-and-install-a-package) in VS, and you can use the command like `Update-Package -Project YourProjectName`. More details see this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876732/how-do-i-get-nuget-to-install-update-all-the-packages-in-the-packages-config).

> How about is there a way to show the .NET framework of the SPECIFIC
>   application on a web server.

In my opinion you're trying to find a way to get the target framework of an assembly. Since the build output of a web-app is a xx.dll, actually you're trying to know what the target framework of the assembly. There're many tools and workarounds for this requirement, you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325918/how-to-find-out-which-version-of-the-net-framework-an-executable-needs-to-run).

For this topic, I suggest you can either use **[Sean B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40211399/10910450)**'s or **[Asain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40211399/10910450)**'s suggestion:

1. Use notepad to open the assembly and find the last `framework` keyword:

[image]

2. Or use `find "Framework" WebApp.dll` in cmd.exe(It should be **Framework** instead of **framework**):

[image]

Hope all above helps and if I misunderstand anything, feel free to let me know :)